# How to get current domain name with Python/GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Current url is

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/something/<user-id>
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/something/<user-id>
```

How in my python code I can get `http://myapp.appspot.com/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`?
This is need for dynamic links generation, for ex., to `http://myapp.appspot.com/somethingelse`.

`self.request.path` returns the whole path.

Comment: Why not use relative URLs? `<a href="/somethingelse">` will work from anywhere on your site to the appropriate URL on the same host.

Comment: I am creating RSS. Relative URLs will not work there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[self.request.host_url](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#method-url)

Comment: Thanks, it works well. Another option I've found is to use `self.request.environ['HTTP_HOST']`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [app_identity.get_default_version_hostname()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/).

> If an app is served from a custom domain, it may be necessary to
>   retrieve the entire hostname component. You can do this using the
>   app_identity.get_default_version_hostname() method.

This code:
`logging.info(app_identity.get_default_version_hostname())`

prints `localhost:8080` on the development server.

Comment: Needs `from google.appengine.api import app_identity`

Answer (score 0):

If `self.request.path` returns the whole path, can't you just do:

```
import urlparse

def get_domain(url):
    return urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc
```

```
>>> get_domain("http://myapp.appspot.com/something/")
'myapp.appspot.com'
```

Comment: It returns empty string (at least when used locally)

Comment: There needs to be a `//` before the domain name, otherwise it is assumed that it is a relative url.